# Search is very slow for certain roles

Tags: search, 9, debugging

I'm a bit lost here. I have a strange problem and don't know where to begin. I use the core search function on a website I build. When I am logged in as administrator this search function is working and is very fast. When I log in as one of the users (with other role and permissions) the search function is very slow and sometimes even ending up in a 504 page.

I can't think of a good starting point to find out what the problem is. Who can help me think of a good debugging path?

Comment: It is possibly access checking. What sort of database is it and how is it set up?

Comment: As @cilefen said access checking is the most likely cause. I would guess that a module hook is altering the query to add access checking for non-admin users and this is not-performant for some reason.

Comment: Hhmm I am using the permissions by term module. This could be the problem. I’ll have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question about how to debug: you have to use a technique called “profiling”. By far the easiest PHP profiler to use is https://www.blackfire.io/. I’ve used it and I recommend it. Xdebug can profile too but by there is a lot to understand to use it https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: I have answered this question "Who can help me think of a good debugging path?" here.